# Migrating Mule 3 to Mule 4 - sfdc Query Single

Tags: salesforce, mule, mulesoft

Am migrating an existing Mule 3 api that interacts with Salesforce.
In mule 3 we are using `Query Single` as below:

```
<sfdc:query-single config-ref="XYZ" query="dsql:SELECT abc blah blah" doc:name="GET Customer Details Query"/>
```

While in Mule 4 I dont see an equivalent of `Query Single`
Where do I get `Query Single` in case of Mule 4 ?

At the moment am using `Query` in Mule 4

```
<salesforce:query doc:name="Query" config-ref="Salesforce_Connector">
        <salesforce:salesforce-query ><![CDATA[#[ SELECT abc blah blah ]]]></salesforce:salesforce-query>
</salesforce:query>
```

As a result in case of Mule 3 the response is an Object Vs In Mule 4 an array :
**Mule 3 response**:

```
{
"Id":null,
"type":"XYZ__c",
"ABCNumber__c":"123456789"
}
```

**Mule 4 response**:

```
[
  {
    "Id":null,
    "type":"XYZ__c",
    "ABCNumber__c":"123456789"
  }
]
```

While I can choose to select the first element of array , I would prefer if I could use `Query Single` if it was available in Mule 4 ?

Google search is not really providing any details ....
so was wondering if `Query Single` for SFDC  is available in Mule 4  ?
If not what is the best approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the first element if it exists is a right way to use Salesforce query in Mule 4. Since there is no Query Single operation you should take the first element, if it exists. Having said that the [Query operation is deprecated since the 10.13 release of the Salesforce Connector](https://docs.mulesoft.com/salesforce-connector/10.18/salesforce-connector-upgrade-migrate#10-13) and you should use the [Query XML Stream](https://docs.mulesoft.com/salesforce-connector/10.18/salesforce-connector-reference#queryXmlStream) operation instead.